# Link_to not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a simple app using Ruby on Rails. Essentially, I have a route that maps to a controller, whose view looks like this:

```
<div class="wishlist-container">
<% @wishlists.each do |w| %>
    <div class="wishlist-card">
        <h4><%= w.title %></h4>
        <%= link_to "View List", wishlist_path(w) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything works correctly **except for the link**. For whatever reason, the link links to "." instead of "/" where `<id>` is the id. For example, it should link to `/wishlist/1` but instead goes to `/wishlist.1`.

What is happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the routes you have defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using paths helpers in your code , you should specify the resources , not only `get` or `post` in your `routes.rb` 
for example if you've

`get 'wishlist/:id'` It may not work .To make your path work you should specify 
`get 'wishlist/:id', to: 'wishlist#show', as: 'wishlist'`

For more information read [Ruby docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [This article](https://viget.com/extend/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url)